# How to run rails application cloned from github in digitalocean?

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-4, github, digital-ocean

I used the one-click setup from digitalocean to setup an "*Ubuntu Ruby on Rails on 14.04 (Postgres, Nginx, Unicorn)*" server.

I successfully **cloned** and **bundle install** and **migrate** my database. However, when I run my server using '**rails s**'. I can't seems access it from port 3000.

I am suspecting it has something to do with the pre-configuration digitalocean has setup.

does anyone knows the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

ok i figured it out

1. make sure to create `/home/index.html` and point your route there
   before you push to git
2. install git `apt-get install git`
3. ssh to your digitalocean domain
4. navigate to `cd /home/rails`
5. delete folder rails
6. clone your rails repo from github `git clone YOUR_REMOTE_ADDRESS`
7. rename the downloaded repo to rails
8. setup your db `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`
9. run rails server like so `rails s --binding=YOUR_IP_ADDRESS`
10. go your your browser and input your ip plus ":3000"

I was running `rails s` for the past few days wondering why it is just showing the default "digitalocean rails page"

anyways, i hope this could help someone in the future.